# Combine Cordova 3.x JS files all into one like in 2.x

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to have my PhoneGap app read pages from the internet and use the enhanced native functionality that PG offers.

Sharing and including the `cordova.js` is one step ahead but any plugins in the new architecture causes nuisance. Is there a way to combine the plugins and `cordova.js` all in one? The JS optimizers don't work on the module system that is used in the plugin architecture.

I could also go the versions prior 3.0 but I suspect they aren't as nice.

Edit: I noticed today that cordova 2.9.1 has combined all modules in one file and the code looks just like what I tried in 3.0. Perhaps the build process over that is public somewhere.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am looking to do the same thing.

Comment: @JeffMartin: sadly, no.

Comment: I found this script that will combine the plugin js files and insert them into the cordova.js file. https://github.com/borisnieuwenhuis/cordovapackageplugins. It is working well for me.

Comment: @JeffMartin: it looks promising if a bit rough. I chose to stay in 2.9.1 but why not wrap that in an answer with a bit of description on how you use that? :)